# Get key hash for release

Tags: android, facebook, hash

I have just release my android app and am getting key hash does not match error I have tried going through the terminal and got a key hash and put in the Facebook dev website but it still didn't work, now I am trying to log the key hash like is says to in the getting started guide and a bunch of SO question that I have been looking at for hours, but it seems the code is out of date, as I am getting an error for the `.toByteArray()`, and it doesn't work so any help on how to get this code to log my key hash or get it, would be great thanks. Heres my code

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

I have put this in my on create on my main activity.

Comment: what error does it throw? perhaps paste the exception stack

Comment: @waqaslam I got it to log now but I pasted that into Facebook dev app but I still get the key hash doesn't match in my app? does it take time for it to update i hit save?

Comment: Sorry, no idea about the facebook stuff you are talking about. I thought its the problem in getting the hash key for an apk.

Comment: @waqaslam when I am loging it I am doing it on an emulator, but it is running the same think as the released version does that matter?

Comment: The certificate used for release is different than the debug version. Hence you should test this on a released version.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you import this

```
import android.content.pm.Signature;
```

and not this

```
import java.security.Signature;
```

Comment: hey ya i got that working if you wouldn't mind could you look at this cause I still have the error  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27813322/get-key-hash-for-release

Comment: Ok, I put an answer for that question. Please mark this one as Accepted if it logged your keyhash. Thanks!